# If there is no Table then do else

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007, word-2003

I want to find some `text` if this text is in table then convert the table into text else do nothing

But when there is no `Table` it gives an `Error`

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = " - ^$^$^$^$ ^$ - ^$^$^$^$^$^$"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
If Selection.Find.Found = True Then

Selection.Tables(1).Select ' This is Error position

Selection.Rows.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByTabs, NestedTables:= _
    True

Else
End If
```

and I want it to `do` it in `loop`

Comment: if selection.tables.count>-0 then.....   for I =1 to selection.tables.count .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition, if Selection.Tables.Count > 0 to your code

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " - ^$^$^$^$ ^$ - ^$^$^$^$^$^$"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    If Selection.Find.Found = True Then

    If Selection.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        Selection.Tables(1).Select ' This is Error position

        Selection.Rows.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByTabs, NestedTables:=True
    End If
End If
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

@nathan_sav thanks

Following is working code in `loop`

```
do
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
   .Text = " - ^$^$^$^$ ^$ - ^$^$^$^$^$^$"
   .Forward = True
   .Wrap = wdFindStop
   .Format = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
If Selection.Find.Found = True Then

if selection.tables.count>0 then
Selection.Tables(1).Select 

Selection.Rows.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByTabs, NestedTables:= _
True
else
end if


Else
exit do
End If
loop
```